# Meteor user undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

When I do a

```
console.log Meteor.user() // on client script, coffeeScript
```

I am able to find this on standard chrome but not in all other browsers
not sure if there is anything I need to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do again?

Comment: I am trying to write a simple if else function if(Meteor.user()){// do something...} however Meteor.user() return undefined in other browsers other than chrome

Comment: Just checking: You're signed in the other browsers, right?

Comment: yup, I have tired other browsers like safari and chrome canary, all returns undefined after signed in, if is logout returns null, but I have no idea why it work on my default chrome browser.

Comment: I fix this by using setTimeout(-> console.log Meteor.user(), 1000) anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use deps.autorun

```
Deps.autorun
  if Meteor.user()
    # continue the code here...CoffeeScript
```

According to their document:

> Deps.autorun allows you to run a function that depends on reactive
>   data sources, in such a way that if there are changes to the data
>   later, the function will be rerun.